# Keep spell check dictionaries syncronized

Tags: sync, spell-check

Each program and computer that I use seems to have its own spell check dictionary.  My web browser has a different dictionary than my word processor. When I use my laptop rather than my desktop, the programs on that computer don't sync the spell check data from my desktop.

Is there a solution for keeping spell check dictionaries (especially the words that I add to dictionaries) in sync across multiple applications and multiple computers?

Answer (score 0):

To keep my custom dictionaries in word processors in sync, I use bitTorrent Sync and just keep the folder the dictionary lives in, in sync across my computers. I don't personally know of a way to keep all dictionaries across all applications in sync. I imagine that'd be a difficult task.